# BULK INSERT in SQL SERVER Truncation Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

While trying to bulk insert an excel file into a table, I am getting the following error

> 42000 - [SQL Server]Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2, column 5 (service_center).

The tab delimited file looks something like this

```
protocol    address  date   type    body    service_center  read_status status  date_sent   readable_date   contact_name
0   AM-GIBSBS   " 14,98,31,75,95,113 "  1   "Apply for MBA in 3rd Best B-School, Residential Campus, 100% Placement, Education Loan Asst., Avail Scholarship - Missed Call 08030072318 / www.gibsbschool.com"   +919892081135   1   -1  1.49832E+12 "Jun 24, 2017 20:49:55" (Unknown)
```

My bulk insert and create table code looks something like this

```
CREATE TABLE sms_tbl (
    protocol VARCHAR(50),
    address VARCHAR(50),
    type VARCHAR(50),
    body VARCHAR(500),
    service_center VARCHAR(50),
    read_status VARCHAR(50),
    status VARCHAR(50),
    date_sent VARCHAR(50),
    readable_date VARCHAR(50),
    contact_name VARCHAR(50))


BULK INSERT sms_tbl
    FROM 'C:\Users\BIKASH-pc\SmsCallContact\SMS_Bikash.txt'
        WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',FIRSTROW=2)
```

Upon changing the body column to the beginning as the 1st column, the code seems to be working fine. I am not able to find out the reason why this error is taking place.

Comment: Your file shouldn't contain headers in a bulk insert operation. In a bulk insert, all rows should be data rows only; header rows will cause issues. Please see Microsoft's [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) on this "The FIRSTROW attribute is not intended to skip column headers. Skipping headers is not supported by the BULK INSERT statement." Please remove the header and `FIRSTROW` attribute and retry. Also can you confirm you are providing the data from the row that is experiencing the error?

Comment: Are you inserting the right file? The source file is a `.txt` but you have indicate you are importing a `.csv`?

Comment: Probably you are getting error because of tabs in between quotation "Apply for MBA in 3rd Best B-School, Residential Campus, 100% Placement, Education Loan Asst., Avail Scholarship - Missed Call 08030072318 / www.gibsbschool.com"

Comment: @Rakib I did not know about the Microsoft guidance. Thanks for that. But I am still getting the same error. And I am using a .tsv file as comma does not seem to work as a delimiter in my case.

Comment: My initial thought was that, but  after printing non-printable characters in notepad++ I found out there is in fact no tabs within the quotation mark.

Comment: I don't follow; the 5th column (serice_center) is 50 chars long, the value you try to insert is 159 chars. Isn't that obviously the problem? Also, it seems you are trying to insert 11 columns, but your table only has 10 columns. By the way, shouldn't you define your date columns as a date datatype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just naively counting here, but the error message complains about the fifth column, and that the value is being truncated

Your table definition says service_center is the fifth column, has a max length of 50 chars

The example data you posted doesn't contain any tabs but the data in it has multiple spaces separating things, and "things" always occur at a column position that is divisible by 4, so I'm assuming you've put this data into a text editor with a tab size set to 4, and done a "tabs to spaces" on it before you posted

This means the fifth element of data is:

> "Apply for MBA in 3rd Best B-School, Residential Campus, 100% Placement, Education Loan Asst., Avail Scholarship - Missed Call 08030072318 / www.gibsbschool.com"

Which is clearly longer than 50 chars. If SQLServer is trying to load this into service_center it will fail.

It looks like this data should be in BODY, judging by the file headers, and that this seems a reasonable block of data that would be kept in a "body"

Your file lists a header "DATE" that is not present in your table as a column, and probably this causes an off-by-one error for loading your data, where all columns of data after ADDRESS are being sent into the wrong columns

Fix some combination of these mistakes (maybe just adding a date column to the table at the correct position will be enough) and I'm sure things will work out differently

Comment: @Luv - your edit completely trashed the entire meaning of the answer. Please be more careful